# the error #7001: Error in creating the compiled module file when compiling fortran code with ifort

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran, intel, intel-fortran

I was using the visual studio parallel version 2011 with intel compiler to compile my code by the command:
ifort mymain.f90 /heap-arrays /Qmkl:parallel solver*.obj preconds*.obj
It works well and generates executable files.

But now I changed my workstation, I have to try using visual studio 2022 community version with the Intel oneAPI HPC toolkit.

ifort mymain.f90 /heap-arrays  /module:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\include\intel64\ilp64" /4I8  -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mkl\latest\include" solver*.obj preconds*.obj

Above is the command. I have the main code, mymain.f90, and two subfolders including some *.obj files.
In my main code, I have three modules to define the variables. When I compile it, I have errors with each of the modules: error #7001: Error in creating the compiled module file [module name]

I'm quite new with the compiler commands, I used Intel® oneAPI Math Kernel Library Link Line Advisor to generate the Compiler options. I was wondering if anyone knows what's wrong with my commands or some related settings?

a minimal example:

```
module vars
implicit none
integer :: i,j
real*8  :: numerator, denominator, myvalue
end module

program main
use vars
implicit none
numerator=2.
denominator=4.
myvalue = numerator/denominator
write(*,*)myvalue
end program
```

[compiler results of old version, it works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2goo.png)
[the compiler error of new version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYIsf.png)

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] of some source that doesn't compile with the newer ifort?  That "Error in creating the compiled module file" sounds like a final summary error, like the kind you'd expect to come after some specific detailed error messages.  Scroll back and find the *first* error for each source file.

Comment: [edit] the question with your [mcve].  As you can see, code and error messages are an unreadable mess in comments.  Are you sure the output directory is writeable?  Try `echo > foo.obj` and see if you can create a new file there at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, I edited the question and added the minimal example.

Comment: Yes, I tried echo > foo.obj and it created the object file